# Increment letters like number by certain value in php

Tags: php, phpexcel

In php if I writ

`$c='A';

   $c++;` 
                   it increments to 'B' but if I want to increment it with 2 ,3 or more ,
eg:  $c+2 or $c+3 ,to get the alternate alphabets

```
 for ($column = 'B'; $column < $highestColumn; $column++) {   
 $cell = $worksheet->getCell($column.$row);
 $cell2=$worksheet->getCell($column+1.$row);
 }
```

but the $column+1 dont work

how to do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Incrementing letters will only work with the `++` incrementor operator, not with `+` addition.

If you want to continue using an incrementor, you can use a loop:

```
$column = 'AH';
$step = 7; // number of columns to step by
for($ = 0; $i < $step; $i++) {
    $column++;
}
```

However, PHP's character incrementor won't work backwards, so you couldn't use a negative step value

---

If you want to use addition rather than a loop, then you need to convert that column to a numeric value, do the addition, then convert back

```
$column = 'AH';
$step = 7; // number of columns to step by
$columnNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($column) + $step;
$column = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnNumber - 1);
```

Which has the added benefit of allowing you to use negative step values

Comment: Thanks ,really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increment the character by 2, adding won't work.

Try this instead:

```
echo chr(ord($c) + 2)
```

**Explanation**:

1. Calculate the ascii value of $c using **ord($c)**
2. Add the ascii value by 2.
3. Convert this achii value to string using **chr()** function.

Refer to [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) and [chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) functions.

**Note**:
As [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) specifies, this will only work to Z and not beyond.

Comment: for ($column = 'B'; $column < $highestColumn; $column++) {
     $cell = $worksheet->getCell($column.$row); } 
I want to access the cell which is next to C so that  I can get values in pair for Columns BC ,DE ,FG